# Is it possible to view the source code of dependencies of a contract in Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, erc-721

Let's take [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6206d330d018cfdca00c7e9e210c79d51c6b1d07#code) contract on **Etherscan** as example.

After Open Zeppelin dependencies, we found this:

```
import "./ERC721A.sol";
import "../interfaces/IMerkle.sol";
import "../interfaces/IClaimMerkle.sol";
```

**Is it possible to view the source code of these dependencies?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down the page about etherscan, you can see the code about all file that include this smart contract.

ERC721A.sol
[image]

IMerkle.sol
[image]

IClaimMerkle.sol
[image]

Comment: What a mess!  Before, I scrolled down the page but the cursor was at the bottom of the page so when inside the first file, instead of scrolling the page, it scrolls only that window!